# loop through directory names using a batch file?

Tags: loops, batch-file

Assume I have this structure:

```
d:/
  -- /alpha/
  -- /beta/
  -- /gamma/
  -- /delta/
```

I'm trying to execute a batch file that goes through those folders (but not through sub-folders within them).

How do I get this result using a FOR LOOP (assuming I don't know the name and quantity of the folders):

```
ren alpha alpha1
ren beta beta1
ren gamma gamma1
ren delta delta1
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is all you should need -- directly at the command prompt:

```
for /D %i in (*) do rename "%i" "%i1"
```

or in a batch file (note the doubled `%`):

```
for /D %%i in (*) do rename "%%i" "%%i1"
```

The **/D** performs the command against the directory names, as per the help, which can be obtained using the command `for /?`

> If Command Extensions are enabled, the following additional forms of
> the FOR command are supported:
>
> FOR /D %variable IN (set) DO command [command-parameters]
>
> ```
> If set contains wildcards, then specifies to match against directory
> names instead of file names.
> ```

Comment: Simple and effective. `*` would work just as well as `*.*`, by the way.

Comment: `for /D %%a in (*) do rename "%%a" "%%a1"` <--- use this style in a batch file.  The important changes are the doubled percent signs, and the quotes allow you to handle long path names.

Comment: Ah yes, enclosing the names in quotation marks is a good idea too, thanks for the heads-up @foxidrive.

Comment: This will run the command for the current directory! What changes to make to run it for any specific directory, say `C:\New` ?

Comment: Just put the path where the wildcards are, e.g. (c:\new\\*)

Comment: @Neoryder, put them in parentheses ()