# Rename folder in users directory using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, rename

I'm a little new to scripting and would like help renaming a folder in every users directory.  I would like to accomplish the below but it sounds like I would have to use a FOR loop to go through every user profile.  Does someone have an example of how to accomplish this or maybe another method?

```
ren "C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\TEST" "C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\TEST1"
```

Comment: Check this answer to a similar question. Good luck! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379828/loop-through-directory-names-using-a-batch-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use FOR /D to match only directories

```
 FOR /D %%G IN (C:\users\*) DO (
    ren "%%G\AppData\TEST" "TEST1"
    )
```