# Search folders by name of files and print content

Tags: windows, batch-file, pdf, printing, cmd

I have **Folder A** with multiple pdf files named:

```
FL001.pdf
FL002.pdf
FL003.pdf
etc.
```

And a **Folder B** with subdirectories that contain other folders named after the files in **Folder A** that contains other .pdf files, like this:

```
FL000-099
        FL001
           - 001100.pdf
           - 001101.pdf
        FL002
           - 002100.pdf
           - 002101.pdf
        FL003
           - 003100.pdf
           - 003101.pdf
FL100-199
        FL101
           - 101100.pdf
           - 101101.pdf
        FL102
           - 102100.pdf
           - 102101.pdf
        F3003
           - 103100.pdf
           - 103101.pdf
 etc.
```

And I also have a network printer.

---

**What I'm trying to do:**

By following the names of the .pdf files in **Folder A** search the corresponding subdirectories in **Folder B**; IF exists then send to the printer the .pdf file from **Folder A** and then send to the printer all the .pdf files in the corresponding subdirectory from **Folder B**, then go to the next file and repeat the process for all the names/files in Folder A.

Printing the .pdf's in Folder A is ok, but I need help for the second part which is not working. If I change the `current_directory` to `...\Folder B\FL000-099\` it works, but I need to search in all subdirectories from the original path. (see code below)

---

**What I have done**

```
@echo off 
set current_directory=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder B\
set art_directory=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder A\

set filename=FL001
set extension=.pdf

set tofind=%current_directory%%filename%
set tofind2=%art_directory%%filename%

set tofindextension=%tofind2%%extension%


IF EXIST %tofindextension% ( "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %tofindextension% -print-to "\\server\printer"
    ) ELSE (
        echo "No file!"
    )

IF EXIST %tofind%\ (
    FOR /R %tofind% %%F in (*.pdf*) do "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %tofind%\%%~nxF -print-to "\\server\printer"

    )  ELSE (

        echo "No file!"
    )


pause
```

---

**Is it possible to search as described above? Can you help me with a solution?**

Comment: You first need to change your code like this `SET "Var_Name=Variable String Value"` and reference your variables like this `"%Var_Name%"` or `"%Var_Name%\"` **It's all about the doublequotes**

Comment: `F3003` in your example should read `FL103`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following batch script does exactly what you have asked for. You have no loops in your script, but you should have to, see [here how to loop through files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138538/8051589) and [here how to loop through directories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19380194/8051589).

Three loops are needed, the first is needed to loop through your files in `Folder A`. The second loops through all subdirectories in `Folder B`. The last loop gets all files in that sub directory to compare them with the file of `Folder A`.

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem set directories
set "current_directory=C:\Users\andre_kampling\Desktop\batTest\Folder B"
set "art_directory=C:\Users\andre_kampling\Desktop\batTest\Folder A"
rem set extension
set "extension=txt"


rem loop through all files of "Folder A"
pushd "%art_directory%"
for /r %%f in ("*.%extension%") do (
   set "curFileA=%%~nf"
   set "curFileAFull=%%f"
   rem loop through all directories of "Folder B"
   for /d %%d in ("%current_directory%\*") do (
      set "curDirB=%%d"
      rem is in "Folder B\*" a folder with the name of file in "Folder A"?
      set "curSubDirB=!curDirB!\!curFileA!"

      if exist "!curSubDirB!\" (
         rem file exists print file of "Folder A" and all files found
         rem in sub directory
         echo.
         echo Subfolder is existent "!curSubDirB!"
         call :print curFileAFull

         rem loop through all files in that subdirectory    
         pushd "!curSubDirB!"
         for /r %%g in ("*.%extension%") do (
            set "file=%%g"
            call :print file
         )
         popd
      )
   )
)
popd

pause
exit /B

rem function definitions
:print
set "arg=!%1!"
echo File "%arg%" will be printed...
"C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" %arg% -print-to "\\server\printer"
```

Comment: Instead of moving `for /R` into a sub-routine, you could also put `pushd "\root\path"` before and `popd` after it as `for /R` defaults to the current directory...

Comment: @aschipfl: Yeah your absolutely right! I will improve my answer when I have time.

Comment: @User552853: I updated the batch script, now it should work perfectly with your situation. Before my edit it has problems with spaces in paths, I changed that and tested it. It works.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the requirements right, some stacked For, an If and a call should do without all that variables.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal

Set "DirA=A:\FolderA"
Set "DirB=A:\FolderB"
PushD "%DirA%"
For %%A in ("FL*.pdf"
) Do For /F "delims=" %%B in (
  'Dir /B/AD/S "%DirB%\%%~nA"'
) Do If Exist "%%~fB\*.pdf" (
  Call :Print "%%~fA"
  For %%C in ("%%~fB\*.pdf") Do Call :Print "%%~fC"
)
PopD
Pause
Goto :Eof
:Print
Echo "C:\Program Files\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe" "%~1" -print-to "\\server\printer"
Goto :Eof
```

If the output looks right remove the echo in the last line.

Answer (score 2):

I would not do a recursive search in the directory tree `Folder B` for each file in `Folder A`, because the target sub-directories are located on a fixed hierarchy depth anyway. This is a possible solution:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_CUR_DIR=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder B"
set "_ART_DIR=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder A"
set "_PATTERN=*.pdf"
set "_PRN_EXE=%ProgramFiles%\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"
set "_PRN_SWI=-print-to"
set "_PRINTER=\\server\printer"

rem // Loop through first directory and enumerate the matching files:
for %%A in ("%_ART_DIR%\%_PATTERN%") do (
    rem /* Loop through the second directory and only enumerate the
    rem    immediate sub-directories: */
    for /D %%B in ("%_CUR_DIR%\*") do (
        rem /* Simply check whether a sub-directory exists having the
        rem    same name as the current file in the first directory: */
        if exist "%%~B\%%~nA\" (
            rem /* Print the file from the first directory and all files
            rem    located in the found sub-directory: */
            for %%P in ("%%~A" "%%~B\%%~nA\%_PATTERN%") do (
                ECHO "%_PRN_EXE%" "%%~P" %_PRN_SWI% "%_PRINTER%"
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

After having successfully tested the script, **remove the upper-case `ECHO` commands** in order to actually print any files!

---

If you want the files in `Folder B` to be printed in ascending (alphabetical) order by their names, the inner-most `for` loop must be replaced by a `for /F` loop together with `dir /O:N`, because else the sort order depends on the file system:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_CUR_DIR=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder B"
set "_ART_DIR=C:\Users\user\Desktop\Folder A"
set "_PATTERN=*.pdf"
set "_PRN_EXE=%ProgramFiles%\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe"
set "_PRN_SWI=-print-to"
set "_PRINTER=\\server\printer"

rem // Loop through first directory and enumerate the matching files:
for %%A in ("%_ART_DIR%\%_PATTERN%") do (
    rem /* Loop through the second directory and only enumerate the
    rem    immediate sub-directories: */
    for /D %%B in ("%_CUR_DIR%\*") do (
        rem /* Simply check whether a sub-directory exists having the
        rem    same name as the current file in the first directory: */
        if exist "%%~B\%%~nA\" (
            rem // Print the file from the first directory:
            ECHO "%_PRN_EXE%" "%%~A" %_PRN_SWI% "%_PRINTER%"
            rem /* Print all files located in the found sub-directory,
            rem    sorted alphabetically in ascending order: */
            for /F "delims= eol=|" %%P in ('
                dir /B /A:-D /O:N "%%~B\%%~nA\%_PATTERN%"
            ') do (
                ECHO "%_PRN_EXE%" "%%~B\%%~nA\%%~P" %_PRN_SWI% "%_PRINTER%"
            )
        )
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```